# Using R to read checkbox values in PDF files

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

I have a number of PDF files with data in checkbox form.

I need to read these checkbox values (selected/not selected), but I am unable to figure out how to do this in R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A sample PDF is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_Q5sg6JII7Gf4VO3WoZ4UoP_36y_R0b/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I am not able to get access yo the PDF file with checkbox form